# Establishing a client server Communication in JAVA?

Tags: java, sockets

I want to perform a two way communication between the client and the server and so far i have achieved one way communication. 
My code in JAVA looks like,

**ServerSide**

```
    public class server{
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            try{
            ServerSocket s=new ServerSocket(9998);
            Socket ss=s.accept();
            DataInputStream din=new DataInputStream(ss.getInputStream());
            DataInputStream uip=new DataInputStream(System.in);
            DataOutputStream dout=new DataOutputStream(ss.getOutputStream());
            System.out.println("Enter message to send to client\n");
            String stc=uip.readLine();
            dout.writeBytes(""+stc);
            din.close();
            dout.close();
            uip.close();    
        }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println(e);
            }`enter code here`
    }
    }
```

**ClientSide**

```
   public class client{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try{
        Socket ss=new Socket("localhost",9998);
        DataInputStream din=new DataInputStream(ss.getInputStream());
        DataInputStream uip=new DataInputStream(System.in);
        DataOutputStream dout=new DataOutputStream(ss.getOutputStream());
        String msg=din.readLine();
        System.out.println("Received msg is "+msg);

        din.close();
        dout.close();
        uip.close();


    }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
}
}
```

I tried to get input in the client side and tried to send in the same way to server. but thats not working. Where am i getting wrong? How Should i achieve a two way communication.

In the client side i got input from user and used `.writeBytes(value);` and performed `readLine()` in din in the server side as i have done above in one way communication. But that doesn't work. Where am i doing it wrong?

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: I think you are sending something from server to client but are never sending from client to server (looking from the code).

Comment: The communication should be send-receive (bi-directional). (1) The client is not sending anything to Server (2) The client is not reading what the server sent on the socket.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach to create a double communication system is to create two threads one for writing messages and one to receive messages (both on client and server side).

The listening thread receive a message wake itself and do something. If a response is needed it create the response and add it to a queue.

The writing thread periodically check the queue of messages to be sent. If there are it sends them.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best way for bidirectional client server communication.. "dout.shutdownOutput();" code this line after send function in client side.This is the function named as half socket closed it will helps to back and forth communication.